# Access advanced features and commands of GUI from rhythmbox-client?

Tags: rhythmbox, music, music-player

Does `rhythmbox-client` include actions like loading a playlist and playing it, viewing playlists or list of songs, shuffling the playlist and current play order?

Basically can I do everything i can do with the GUI, from the terminal using `rhythmbox-client` or do I need something else?

I read the `man` page but it displays a basic list of commands, and not much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rhythmbox-client out-of-the box does not have all of the capability you are seeking.

Just for the record, rhythmbox-client supports the following command line options:

```
rhythmbox-client --help
Usage:
  rhythmbox-client [OPTION…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                               Show help options

Application Options:
  --debug                                  
  --no-start                               Don't start a new instance of Rhythmbox
  --quit                                   Quit Rhythmbox
  --check-running                          Check if Rhythmbox is already running
  --no-present                             Don't present an existing Rhythmbox window
  --next                                   Jump to next song
  --previous                               Jump to previous song
  --seek                                   Seek in current track
  --play                                   Resume playback if currently paused
  --pause                                  Pause playback if currently playing
  --play-pause                             Toggle play/pause mode
  --play-uri=URI to play                   Play a specified URI, importing it if necessary
  --enqueue                                Add specified tracks to the play queue
  --clear-queue                            Empty the play queue before adding new tracks
  --print-playing                          Print the title and artist of the playing song
  --print-playing-format                   Print formatted details of the song
  --select-source=Source to select         Select the source matching the specified URI
  --activate-source=Source to activate     Activate the source matching the specified URI
  --play-source=Source to play from        Play from the source matching the specified URI
  --set-volume                             Set the playback volume
  --volume-up                              Increase the playback volume
  --volume-down                            Decrease the playback volume
  --print-volume                           Print the current playback volume
  --set-rating                             Set the rating of the current song
```

`rhythmbox-client` uses a capability called dbus - made accessible when you have the "MPRIS D-Bus plugin" enabled.

You'll need to write an external application that utilises this interface.  A good starting point is this project:

- https://github.com/AeonAxan/Rhythmbox-Remote

This is a python project - you run the python file with command-line parameters just like rhythmbox-client.  You'll need to extend the functionality to support what particularly you are interested in.

Comment: I know what commands `rhythmbox-client` currently supports and I use them in whatever way possible. Could you emphasize about the dbus capability which will make your answer more to the point.

Comment: I could - what specifically are you interested in?

Comment: how to use it and what extra commands will it give me access to?

Comment: That's why I pointed you at the project - if you want a "how do I use dbus" question, then please ask it.